# Minecraft Mob Spawner wont work. Why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

[image]

Why does this mob spawner not working? We are 117 blocks up and the nearest cave below is is lower than 45. The difficulty is set to hard.

Comment: Can you please make another screenshot in which the brightness is set to "bright" instead of "moody"? I literally only see a black rectangle. Opening in a new tab and setting my screen brightness to maximum allows me to see that there is something there, but not what.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that I can think of off the top of my head:

- Is this a multiplayer server? Having other players online will allow
  mobs to spawn near them, filling the [mob cap](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Mob_Cap_2).
- Mobs can spawn anywhere within 128 blocks of a player. To find a good spot to AFK at, find a spot where the mob farm is within 128 blocks of the player but other spawning spaces either: aren't, or are modified to prevent mob spawning (using light sources or non-spawnable blocks like half slabs).